# grep all characters including newline

Tags: regex, grep

I'm parsing an XML file with

```
"lalala it's a Sunday {{ Some words here, maybe
a new line }} oh boy"
```

How would I use grep to get everything within  "{{" and "}}" given that the grep `.` character doesn't recognize newlines?

Currently I have

```
grep '{{.*}}'
```

but it only works on things that are on the same line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option is to remove the newline and then grep, as in:

```
 cat myfile | tr -d '\n' | grep {{.*}}
```

But if you say this is an XML file, why not use an XML parser that takes advantage of the file's inherent structure rather than just regexp?

**EDIT**

Grep regexp are greedy, you can use perl regexp:

```
cat myfile | tr -d '\n' | perl -pe 's/.*?({{.*?}})/\1\n/g' | grep {{
```

This should output one match per line. If you have nested {{ then this will get even more complicated.

Comment: It does the cat but now the grep doesn't work - it returns the entire file. What gives?

Answer (score 2):

This is the way i solved that problem

```
   grep '{{[\s\S]*}}'
```

Comment: `\s` and `\S` are PCRE extensions, not available in standard grep.

Answer (score 1):

You can use alternation between mutually exclusive character sets to match truly any character. For example, this command:

```
grep -E "\{\{([[:digit:]]|[^[:digit:]])+\}\}"
```

...will match anything (greedily) between the first `{{` and last `}}`.

But as @JesseCohen states, you really, really, really should be parsing XML with an XML parser, [not regexps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: If you must know, I'm trying to extract parts of a wikipedia dump XML file that contains unstructured data (all of the above potentially contained within `<text xml:space="preserve">`). So I think the XML parsing is a bit less relevant here.

Comment: Wow, I did just that (the wikipedia dump thing). You might find it a lot harder than it seems (at least I did).

Comment: Moreover, I think using a XML parser requires to load all the file at once, and that Wiki dump is HUGE.

Comment: @Noam Not if it's a streaming SAX parser, e.g. http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/SAX.html

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
grep -zo '[[:cntrl:][:print:]]'
```