# Match Anything In Between Strings For Linux Grep Command

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep, pattern-matching

I have read the post [grep all characters including newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058680/grep-all-characters-including-newline) but I not working with XML so it's a bit different with my Linux command.

I have the following data:

```
Example line 0</span>
<tag>Example line 1</tag>
<span>Example line 1.5</span>
<tag>
Example line 2
</tag>
Example line 3
<span>Example line 4</span>
```

Using this command `cat file.txt | grep -o '<tag.*tag>\|^--.*'` I get:

```
<tag>Example line 1</tag>
```

However, I want the output to be:

```
<tag>Example line 1</tag>
<tag>Example line 2</tag>
```

How can I match anything between the strings, including the newline?

Note: I need to used `<tag` and `tag>` as strings because other files can contain multiple tags and text in between the lines. Will update sample data to show that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easier done with `gnu-awk` using `</tag>` as record separator:

```
awk -v RS='</tag>' 'RT {gsub(/\n/, ""); print $0 RT}' file

<tag>Example line 1</tag>
<tag>Example line 2</tag>
```

Comment: Need to use `<tag` and `tag>` to get between them. Updating sample data. Sorry :-/

Comment: ok try this: `awk -v RS='</tag>' 'RT {gsub(/.*?<tag>|\n/, ""); print "<tag>" $0 RT}' file`

Comment: Hey Anbhava, this works! I'm going to make another question to build on this. Thank you :-)

Comment: Hey Anubhava, any chance you could tell me how to also match for lines starting with "Example" too? If not, I made a question on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40052458/match-multiple-strings-in-awk-command-using-rs-and-rt

Answer (score 0):

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat file2
Example line 0</span>
<tag>Example line 1</tag>
<span>Example line 1.5</span>
<tag>
Example line 2
</tag>
Example line 3
<span>Example line 4</span>
```

This produces the output that you want (requires GNU sed):

```
$ sed -z 's|\n||g; s|</tag>|&\n|g; s|[^\n]*<tag>|<tag>|; s|\n[^\n]*<tag>|\n<tag>|g; s|\n[^\n]*$|\n|' file2
<tag>Example line 1</tag>
<tag>Example line 2</tag>
```

**Limitation:** Note that processing XML-like text with non-specialized tools can be quite *fragile*.

Comment: Hey John, sorry, the data does have other tags. My example was too minimalist. I have updated it at bit.

Comment: @DomainsFeatured See updated answer for code that handles the revised input file.